# Why does my checkbox not have a label? - Ruby on Rails - HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to get a checkbox to show a label and not having much luck.  Here is my code:

```
= form.check_box :site_id, { :inline_label => site.name, :rel => 'onOff' }, site.try(:id), nil
```

I get the checkbox, which works fine, but I do not have a label.  I thought the `:site_id` would be the label.  When I try to add a string for the site id, I get a no method error.  I even tried to add a lable like this:

```
%label.checkbox{ :for => "site_id" }
    = form.check_box :site_id, { :inline_label => site.name, :rel => 'onOff' }, site.try(:id), nil
```

I still got the same result.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is really in html page this `form.check_box :site_id` transformed to object with id `site_id`?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: I'm said about the generated html

Comment: Is this actually in an ERB page? if so it's missing some formatting that I'm used to. For example I would expect your checkbox to look like this `<%= form.check_box :site_id, { :inline_label => site.name, :rel => 'onOff' }, site.try(:id), nil %>` course I could just be unfamiliar with what you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

[`check_box`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) helper method used with `form_for`, simply generates a check box and not a label and that is what is happening in your case. In order to get the label for the check box, you would have to specify it explicitly like

```
 = form.label :site_id 
 = form.check_box :site_id, {:rel => 'onOff' }, site.try(:id), nil
```

Also, `inline_label` option is available in `simple_form_for` helpers i.e., when using [`simple_form` gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and is not available in `form_for` helpers.